# Excel Pivot Table - Change default font

Tags: fonts, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

Is it possible to change the default font for a Pivot Table?

We have a report automation module in our application that populates an Excel spreadsheet with a result set from an Oracle SQL query.

Long story short, you upload a template document with all the formatting already done on all the right places, the automation populates the report and sends it off.

Problem is, my template is 100% but when I receive it back after it has been populated with data the font on the pivot tables have changed.

The pivot font in my template is Calibri, but when I open the report the font has changed back to Arial.

Any ideas are welcome.